# Pull dynamic entries using Ajax template on multiple Structure entries with Relationships

Tags: templates, structure, ajax, embeds, parse

I've created two separate Structure entries, both using the Page template below with Relationship entries. It works fine if I only want one page, but I've made a second page to pull different Relationship entries for each page, but now it's just pulling the same relationship entries for both pages. I tried using `entry_id="{entry_id}` in the `{exp:channel:entries}` on the `recipe_ajax/index` template and that didn't work...only works when I explicitly write the id.

Is there another way to parse the ajax template so that I can use the dynamic `entry_id="{entry_id}` to pull correct entries? Or am I missing something completely obvious?

Here's my Page template:

```
{embed="layouts/index"}

{!-- PAGE CONTENT --}
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes"}

    {exp:channel:entries cache="no" refresh="60" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination"}

        {stash:content}

            <div class="recipes-section add">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="article-holder row" id="container">
                                {recipes_landing_recipes limit="15"}
                                    <div class="grid-item article col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 all {recipes_landing_recipes:categories}{exp:streeng slug='yes'}{category_name} {/exp:streeng} {/recipes_landing_recipes:categories}">
                                        <a href="{route='recipes/recipe_detail' title='{recipes_landing_recipes:url_title}'}">
                                            <div class="img-holder">
                                                <img src="{if recipes_landing_recipes:recipe_featured_image}{recipes_landing_recipes:recipe_featured_image}{if:else}/assets/images/bsl-placeholder.jpg{/if}
                                                " height="366" width="342" alt="{recipes_landing_recipes:title}">
                                            </div>
                                            <strong class="title">{recipes_landing_recipes:title}</strong>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                {/recipes_landing_recipes}
                            </div>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-load" href="{path='recipe_ajax/index'}" style="display: none;">view more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        {/stash:content}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

And here's the `recipe_ajax/index` template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="recipes_landing" cache="no" refresh="60" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination}
    <div class="post-section">
        {recipes_landing_recipes offset="15"}
            <div class="grid-item article col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 all {recipes_landing_recipes:categories}{exp:streeng slug='yes'}{category_name} {/exp:streeng} {/recipes_landing_recipes:categories}">
                <a href="{route='recipes/recipe_detail' title='{recipes_landing_recipes:url_title}'}">
                    <div class="img-holder">
                        <img src="{if recipes_landing_recipes:recipe_featured_image}{recipes_landing_recipes:recipe_featured_image}{if:else}/assets/images/bsl-placeholder.jpg{/if}" height="366" width="342" alt="{recipes_landing_recipes:title}">
                    </div>
                    <strong class="title">{recipes_landing_recipes:title} {recipes_landing_recipes:entry_id}</strong>
                </a>
            </div>
        {/recipes_landing_recipes}
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

I was able to resolve by calling the entry_id_path in the Page template `{entry_id_path='recipe_ajax/index'}` and referencing this path in the ajax file like so `entry_id_path="{entry_id_path}`

Comment: Are you trying to load more related entries from the parent entry or something else?

Comment: Since I was using the same page template without referencing the entry_id in the ajax file, it was just pulling all the entries no matter what relationship entries were selected. I resolved issue and included my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are actually trying to do.

If I understand it all, it seems your link is emulating a pagination link - so the link will open a view of the next block of results from `{recipes_landing_recipes}` results.  If so, perhaps you could just make use of EE's [pagination](http://Not%20sure%20what%20you%20are%20actually%20trying%20to%20do.%20%20If%20I%20understand%20it%20all,%20it%20seems%20your%20link%20is%20emulating%20a%20pagination%20link%20-%20so%20the%20link%20will%20open%20a%20view%20of%20the%20next%20block%20of%20results%20from%20%60%7Brecipes_landing_recipes%7D%60%20results.%20%20If%20so,%20perhaps%20you%20could%20make%20use%20of%20pagination) features to do this.  Would be less complicated I think.

I think you are complicating this by using `{stash}` but since you are, you could perhaps just dump out all the recipes into stash once and then pull them from there when you need them.

HTH